# Vertex shaders vs pixel shaders performance for music visualizations?

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader

I was wondering what would be more suitable for music visualization, vertex or pixel shaders especially as far as performance goes. I tried using pixel shaders like the ones shown on [shadertoy.com](http://shadertoy.com) then I looked at vertex shaders shown on [vertexshaderart.com](http://vertexshaderart.com) and I think the vertex shaders are more performant, but I'm not entirely sure. I was wondering if someone who has had experience in both may have an idea?

Comment: This is like asking "what performs better a knife or a spoon?", certainly depends on if you're eating soup or a steak.

Comment: I just want to say that while you should do whatever you want, neither are really performant. If you want performance than use normal triangles, polygons and models. Of course if you find fragment or vertex shader visualization fun and/or challenging (like programming with your toes) then of course feel free to challenge yourself. Pro visualization software and pro visual artists usually don't limit themselves to shaders only. Examples: [Touchdesigner](https://vimeo.com/122273236), [vvvv](https://vvvv.org/), [Keijiro](https://twitter.com/_kzr), [Sagar](https://twitter.com/_sgrptl)

Answer (score 1):

It very depends on HOW and WHAT you do with vertices and pixels.
It is better to start thinking to the effect you want and then try to refine it or switch to another shader type.
If working with vertices may seems more performing, when post-processing comes (in a fragment shader, anyway) you could find that a pixel/fragment shader would behave better.
Pixel/Fragment shaders anyway are by far the most used in music visualization based on Volume pressure/FFT/Spectrum.

Finally, there are some features that will make you to prefer a vertex shader over a fragment, IE *lighting*, that is easier to get with a per-vertex computing.

Comment: So from my understanding you're saying that it depends on the effect. In some cases pixel shaders will perform better than vertex shaders and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, consider that for placing a vertex _on screen_ you have to pass anyway from a pixel shader. A (IE) glow effect will be done in a fragment.